# Inaccuracy in triangles computation

Tags: geometry

The below link on MSE was a question assuming a second solution was obtained on Mathematica by second method. Appears to be a question of accuracy.

[Big Side of Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582643/two-configurations-around-same-radial-line-lengths-in-a-triangle)

Given are three side lengths $ (AB,AC,AD)=(3,2,4)$. Also $(B,C,D) $ are collinear and $ AB $ is tangent to the circle at $A$.

[image]

The bigger side $BD$ is computed in two ways

1. Direct geometry  By similar triangles
   $$ BD= AB \cdot AD / AC = 3 \cdot 4/2 =6 $$
2. A roundabout method that should give same results.. Cosine Rule on triangles $ \triangle{ABC}$, $\triangle{ACD}$ and tangent property $ BA^2=BC \cdot BD$

   ```
   Clear["Global`*"]
   {a,b,c}={3,2,4};
   BigSide=a*c/b
   NSolve[{x^2==a^2+b^2-2 a b csbt,y^2+c^2-2 c y csbt==b^2,x(x+y)==a^2},{x,y,csbt}]
   dreiQuadrat=1.5 (1.5+4.5)
   dreiQuadrat1=1.5073469747588177*(4.463408366054498+1.5073469747588177)
   ```

Low accuracy is seen in the second solution that is not expected.

Can the accuracy of the second method be improved? If so, how?

Geogebra drawing does not distinguish the circles as the difference is so small.

Thanks in advance for comments.

Comment: I've given my knowledge for Euclidean geometry back to my teacher so cannot analyze the problem, but it doesn't look like a precision issue:  `Solve[{x^2 == a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b csbt, y^2 + c^2 - 2 c y csbt == b^2, 
   x (x + y) == a^2}, {x, y, csbt}, Quartics -> True] // N[#, 32] &`

Answer (score 3):

- The equation doesn't ensure that the three points `B,C,D` are colinear.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
{a, b, c} = {3, 2, 4};
BigSide = a*c/b;
sol = NSolve[{x^2 == a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b csbt, 
    y^2 + c^2 - 2 c y csbt == b^2, x (x + y) == a^2, x > 0, 
    y > 0}, {x, y, csbt}]
```

[image]

- `sol[[1]]` is right since `Cos[ACB]+Cos[ACD]==0`

```
{SolveValues[x^2 + b^2 - 2 x*b*Cos[t] == a^2, Cos[t]], 
  SolveValues[b^2 + y^2 - 2 b*y*Cos[t] == c^2, Cos[t]]} /. sol[[1]]
```

[image]

- `sol[[2]]` is wrong since `Cos[ACB]+Cos[ACD]!=0`

```
{SolveValues[x^2 + b^2 - 2 x*b*Cos[t] == a^2, Cos[t]], 
  SolveValues[b^2 + y^2 - 2 b*y*Cos[t] == c^2, Cos[t]]} /. sol[[2]]
```

[image]

### Edit

If we use Cosine Rule to the angle `ACB==θ` and angle `ACD==π - θ`, then we can get the only one solution.

```
Solve[{x^2 + 2^2 - 2*x*2*Cos[θ] == 3^2, 
  y^2 + 2^2 - 2*y*2*Cos[π - θ] == 4^2, x (x + y) == 3^2, 
  x > 0, y > 0, 0 <= θ <= π}, {x, y, θ}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does the Cosine Rule sometimes bend straight lines? In this case the first analytic solution is available . With many numerical results won't individual verification be cumbersome to remove extraneous ones?

Comment: @Narasimham  Cosine Rule is the relation of the sides and the angles only work in one triangle,  and it actual  work fine in  two triangle ABC and ACD respectly , but we still  need to add condition to ensure that  ABD is a triangle.

Comment: By the circle property  $ BA^2=BC \cdot BD$ Euclid implied that 1) BD is a straight line 2) BC is a straight line 3) Points (B,C,D) are collinear. right?

Comment: @Narasimham  The inversion transformation $BA^2=BC \cdot BD$  work  only when B,C,D  are colinear.

Comment: All output results from  same code should be correct.  Is comment about inversion of circles?